# What type of storage for some text in android?

Tags: android, xml, database, file, storage

I'm making a game to run on android. So I want to store player names and the winner, which I will also list up in a view. What is the best way to do this, use a database or write to a file (if so, what type, xml?). I have to be able to add data after every completed game, and the size won't be so large. What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, using a SQLite database would be the most straightforward.  You don't have to worry about the xml parsing that goes along with an xml file.  Additionally, the data your storing seems to have a natural relationship that would be conducive to a SQLite schema.  For more information about how to use SQLite in Android, see [the data storage documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: Went with this, spent a couple of hours doing it, and it works perfectly! I had tried with xml, and I used like selveral days reading, testing and getting it go work, but I gave up. Sqlite, great solution

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is great if you have database concerns and want that sort of data lookup.

However, if you really want to do it [Simply with XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) then [you can in Android](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).